# Tab completion does not work in MySQL command line client

Tags: mysql, homebrew

I've installed MySQL 5.7.10 on my Mac using Homebrew. My Mac is running OSX 10.11.3.

When I'm running the MySQL command line client, I cannot tab-complete keywords, table or column names.

How do I get it to tab-complete?

```
joenyland@Joes-MBP ~ $ mysql --auto-rehash
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 5.7.10 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Here's the output from `otool`:

```
joenyland@Joes-MBP ~ $ otool -L /usr/local/bin/mysql
/usr/local/bin/mysql:
    /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Comment: Maybe this would have been better suited on http://superuser.com/ 

Comment: Probably, but half of the content here is similar.

Comment: You might first `use database` before you try to auto-complete tables or column names.

Comment: @Otheus Oh my! That's it! Once I `use` a database, I can tab-complete everything - DBs, columns, tables, etc. However before that, pressing tab does not do anything. Want to add an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tab completion for tables and columns works only when you are connected or using a database that has such tables. When you run `mysql` and connect to a sever, unless you have specified on the command line (or via cnf files) the database to connect to, you can see only the mysql system tables. Simply execute `use mydatabase;` to allow all the tables in `mydatabase` to work with tab-completion. Or connect to the database directly on the command line with

```
mysql mydatabase
```

Answer (score 3):

If your `mysql` client is built with `readline`, you can do this using the `auto-rehash` feature.  These are possible solutions:

- command-line option `--auto-rehash`
- command (in `mysql`), type `rehash`
- configuration file called `.my.cnf` in your home directory, containing:

  [mysql]
  auto-rehash

Further reading:

- [Autocompletion in the MySQL command-line client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332338/autocompletion-in-the-mysql-command-line-client)
- [MySQL tab completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070156/mysql-tab-completion-not-working)

The OSX libedit library is more or less the same as readline (some interface differences with the same functionality).  MySQL could be built with either.  For example, these mention it:

- [How to get vi keybindings to work in mysql client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216471/how-to-get-vi-keybindings-to-work-in-mysql-client)
- [Command history in mysql client only showing last line of multiline query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813051/command-history-in-mysql-client-only-showing-last-line-of-multiline-query)

Comment: I still don't get tab-completion with the `--auto-rehash` option. How do I know if I'm using `readline`? I've installed from Homebrew, if that helps...

Comment: In OSX, [`otool`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057234/discovery-of-dynamic-library-dependency-on-mac-os-linux) can show which shared libraries a program is linked with.

Comment: I've just updated the question with the output form `otool -L`. Does this help? It means nothing to me, except suggest that I'm not using `readline`.